# Should I report the standardised or unstandardised coefficient in a regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, reporting

When I run a multiple OLS regression, SPSS will give me a thing called a 'standardized coefficient' and another called an 'unstandardized coefficient'.

I understand that, essentially, the standardised coefficient is useful if you want to know which of the different independent variables is more important. The unstandardised coefficient, on the other hand, is the one you use to find out what effect 1 unit change in x will have on y.

The practical question is this: if I'm writing a paper using a multiple regression, I will have to complete a table with all the results. The problem is that, in this paper, I would want to comment on the standardised coefficient (to compare effects of variables) *as well as* the unstandardised one (to calculate unit changes). So essentially, which coefficient am I supposed to report in a paper in which I make reference to both? Should I include one in the results table and the other one somewhere else?

I've been trying to teach myself some statistics (all social science-related) using SPSS and this is one thing I don't fully understand.

Comment: depends completely on the journal (and the field of research).

Comment: Conventions vary. In the areas I work in I don't think I'd ever report a standardized coefficient. I think if you want to discuss both, you should report both. If I needed to report both I'd put them in a table, unstandardized info (estimate, se), then the standardized estimate, then the common info (t, p) - but as I said, conventions vary by area and even in some cases, by journal. But in any case, find out what your audiences expectations are, and only break those expectations when you have a reason to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standarized coefficient is the change in Y, measured in units of its standard deviation, associated with a 1 standard deviation change in X. So report the standardized coefficents, and in the table also indicate what the standard deviation is for each variable. Then the reader can make whatever comparisons they want for themselves. Highlight any notable results in the text in whatever form makes the most sense - just make sure you are very clear about what you are reporting.

This is largely subjective, and will ultimately depend on the journal, the specfic editor(s) and reviewers and their personal preferences..but this is what I think is a pretty "clean" way to do this.

[Edit based on @Penguin_Knight comment below, which is of course correct]

Comment: OK, that makes a lot of sense. I haven't got to the point of submitting my work to journals, I was just wondering if there was a consensus on the topic. Thanks a lot, I'll stick to your suggestion from now on!

Comment: May I suggest an alternate interpretation? Standardized coefficient should be unitless because its formula is $\beta_1' = \beta_1 \times SD_x / SD_y$, the unit of $\beta_1$ is **unit in y/ unit in x** while the unit of the SDs are their corresponding **unit of x** and **unit of y**. $y/x \times x/y = 1$ and hence there is no unit.